# Connecting Storm with remote Kafka cluster, what would happen if new brokers are added

Tags: apache-kafka

We are working on an application that uses Storm to pull data from a remote Kafka cluster. As the two cluster lies in different environment there is an issue with network connectivity between them. In simple term by default the remote zookeeper and Kafka brokers does not allow connection from our Storm's worker/supervisor nodes. In order to do that we need firewall access to be given.

My concern is what would happen if new Brokers or Zookeeper is added in the remote cluster ? I understand that we don't have to specify all the zk nodes in order to consume but say they add few brokers and we need to consume from a partition which is served by those new set of nodes ? What would be the impact on the running Storm application ?

Comment: We have the same issue. In general, how do remote clients have to connect Kafka? Other messaging solutions have components that address this need implementing gateways (or bridges) that also handle, in background, temporary failures of the communication.